# Файл nohup.out , за что отвечаем?

Tags: linux

Имеется сервер на Linux. В папке /root есть файл `nohup.out`, размером больше 5гб. За что он отвечает и можно ли его удалить без потери информации?

Подозреваю что это какой-то лог работающих в фоне скриптов...

Comment: Можно попробовать поискать, использует ли его что-либо в конкретный момент времени `lsof | grep nohup.out`

Comment: Запусти `man nohup`.

Answer (score 1):

Я погуглил вместо тебя и в принципе нашёл [то, что тебе стоило бы узнать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). Можешь удалять, файл не особо нужный.

Comment: Думаю в ответе не хватает больше информации почему можно удалять, а ссылка должна быть дополнительным источником данных, а не основным :)

Comment: @gil9red вопросов было два у чувака - 1. за что отвечает, и 2. можно ли удалять. За что отвечает можно прочитать по ссылке, смысла нет копировать с места на место, а на второй вопрос я ответил - можно удалять =)

Comment: `можно прочитать по ссылке, смысла нет копировать с места на место`. Ты походу недавно пользуешься интернетом и ещё не в курсе как быстро ссылки имеют свойство протухать из-за смены хостера, проблем с dns, смены движка, ленью ведущего блог, банального rm и т.д.

Comment: @donRumata конечно недавно, позавчера в нашу глубинку телефон кое-как дотянули, вот, через dial-up и сижу. Однако не сомневаюсь, что ссылки на Википедию протухают каждый день пачками, всякий раз, как Википедия меняет хостера, лежит потом как с@ка неделю, не достучишься. Благородный дон не в духе?

Comment: Википедия может и не лежать, но она может (и прекрасно это делает) меняться. Я немного в курсе того ада, который там творится в русскоязычном сообществе модераторов\редакторов. Так что я бы и Вику зеркалил на всякий случай. Потому что могут быть не в духе админы и выпиливать целые статьи пачками. А, про РКН и его ковровые блокировки забыл. Так что да, Википедия может быть недоступна.